# Program opens during install and halts MSI till quit

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

I have been asked to fix a small problem with one of our small product's install. Its a basic .msi file (about 0.5 megs) that was created in Microsoft Visual Studio. When you run the installer it goes and installs the program, just like it should, then when the progress bar is about 99% done the program that it installed loads up, stalling the installer.

If I go and Exit the running program the installer then finishes and lets me exit. If I dont exit the program I have to go into task manager to exit the installer's process.

I have searched everywhere for a solution to this and I cant find anyone else with a similar problem. I have gone though the code and I cant find anything that would be causing this. Is it just a stupid setting that I am missing?

Sorry for being so vague, I don't know what information is relevant. Thanks!

Comment: Two questions: 1. Which version (incl SP) of Visual Studio are you using? 2. A basic MSI created by Visual Studio normally doesn't launch the installed application. I assume you did "something" to do so and the problem could lie in the way you launch the app.

Comment: And a tip: You get a lot of information of what is going on during the installation from an install log. Call the installer from the command line using `msiexec /i mySetup.msi /l*vx log.txt`

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.21022.8 (I believe its updated all the way)

I ran that command and I am digging through the log file. Not quite sure what to look for. Anything I should look for specifically?

Comment: Can you check in the setup project if there is a custom action defined? And if yes, can you post the code here?

Comment: Turns out there is a custom action. Under Commit there is an action labeled "Primary output from [ProgramName] (Active)" Where [ProgramName] is my program. Though there does not seem to be any code associated with it (or at least none I can find). I took out that action and that fixed the problem. Its always the little thing hidding that is the cause. Would you like to post your last comment as an Answer so I can accept it as the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is this:

The installer is set up to run the application *as part of the install process*. This is **wrong**, because then the installer can't move on to the next part of the install (which happens to be finishing everything up and exiting the installer) until the current part is finished. In other words, the install won't finish until you exit the app.

You want to run the application *after* the install has been committed - see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/Installation.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Does the program have some form of self registration that it needs to perform.

Installer Blocks inside it etc.

Check what it does when you run InstallUtil against it.

Comment: The Program is very basic. I am still not too experienced with VB.net, but there does not seem to be any self registration.

How would I go about using InstallUtil? (first job out of school.. Time to really learn!)

Comment: Bring up a .NET command line then run installutil /?
it will give you all the usage
but basically you run InstallUtil /LogFile=sdjfdsajfsaj.txt PathToYourProgram this can be used for debugging any installblocks inside your program.
You can also wire up your Program to use in the Debug Options of your program . Start External Program (installutil).. Command Line Args = path to yourself

Answer (score 0):

Refer the documentation on [Custom Action Return Processing Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368071(VS.85).aspx), your setup is waiting for an error/success return code after running your application. You need to update the custom action that is launching your program to ignore the return code and not wait for execution to complete.